# Inequality involving degrees of field extensions

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, algebraic-groups

Suppose we have fields $F \subset E \subset K$ and $\alpha \in K$. Suppose also that $K$ is algebraic over $E$. Let $\alpha \in K$. Then we have $p(\alpha)=0$ for some $p(x) = a_{0} + a_{1}x+ \dots+a_{n}x^n \in E[x]$.

The claim is that $|F(a_{0}, a_{1}, \dots a_{n}): F| \leq \displaystyle \prod_{i=0}^{n} |F(a_{i}):F| \lt \infty$.

I am not sure why this inequality holds. Would appreciate if someone has an explanation!

Comment: Hint : the degree is multiplicative. Proceed by induction on $n$.

Comment: @Oria Please could you ellaborate.

Comment: The case $n=1$ is clear, since both sides are in fact equal. Now, assuming it holds for $n$, consider the extension tower given by adjoining $n$ elements, and to them adjoining the $n+1$th element and use the multiplicaivity of the degree